# How to control conversion from Asciidoc to HTML

Tags: java, multithreading, asciidoctor

I'm in charge of conversion documents from Asciidoc format to HTML format in desktop application. I use [AsciidoctorJ Java-wrapper](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctorj) library, like this:

```java
Asciidoctor asciidoctor = Asciidoctor.Factory.create();

Options html = OptionsBuilder.options().
                backend("html").
                get();

asciidoctor.convertFile(
                new File("test.asciidoc"),
                html);
```

I would like to provide an ability to cancel the conversion, for example, when a user clicks "Cancel" button on UI of the application the conversion should stop. In order to keep UI responsive, I run the snipped depicted above in separate thread.

As far as I know, [in Java thread can be stopped only in cooperative way](https://codeahoy.com/java/How-To-Stop-Threads-Safely/#:%7E:text=In%20Java%2C%20stopping%20threads%20requires,at%20the%20next%20available%20opportunity.). Methods like `Thread.stop()` are deprecated. And it seems that AsciidoctorJ doesn't provide an ability to cancel the conversion. Thus, `org.asciidoctor.Asciidoctor.convertFile()` (as well as other methods) doesn't return a kind of handler which can be used for controlling the conversion. There is only one method that is more-or-less suitable: `org.asciidoctor.Asciidoctor.shutdown()`.

Documentation of the method claims:

> This method frees all resources consumed by asciidoctorJ module. Keep in mind that if this method is called, instance becomes unusable and you should create another instance.

I'm afraid that shutting down the entire AsciidoctorJ is not good.

Is there better solution?

Comment: Just curious, but how much content is being converted? Even for a 600-page book, Asciidoctor converted all of the content in just a few seconds.

Comment: Content size depends on user's data. Basically, user works in my application with a kind of virtual model. That model is converted to Asciidoc format via my application. And then from Asciidoc to HTML via Asciidoctor. The model may be very huge depending of what the user is modelling. Also, I plan to generate not only HTML but PDF in future. I would like to ensure margin of safety and give the user control over the conversion.

Comment: How long are your conversions taking? And how much markup is involved when it takes long enough that you feel the need to offer a Cancel button? Figuring out the scope of the problem might help decide what solution to undertake.